# How to get post ID when using Google Feed API?

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, rss

I currently have two JS codes I am using to load my posts dynamically from my wordpress:

Code 1: JSON API

```
<script src="http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=recentstories&callback=listPosts" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Code 2: RSS Feed

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/'),
    dataType: 'json',
})
```

The JSON API result includes each post's ID, but that of the RSS Feed when converted by the Ajax Google API does not contain the post ID.

Do I need to modify my Wordpress RSS code to include the post ID?

Comment: Missing a closing `})` on your `ajax()` call...

Comment: any console log errors ?

Comment: @karthikr this is the link to the screenshot to the console.log result http://imgur.com/5ArR0uC

Comment: OK I just noticed that when I view the RSS feed link and drill down after category, I see a <guid>xxx</guild>:

<guid isPermaLink="false">http://howtodeployit.com/?p=442</guid>

this seems to contain each post ID after /?p=. So it looks like I have to find a way to exclude everything up until p= and also exclude </guild> to extract just the ID. This may be advanced for me.

Comment: Anyone able to advise on how I can get Google API to extract the enclosed xml item: <guid isPermaLink="false">howtodeployit.com/?p=442</guid> into JSON?

I have tried the **google.feeds.Feed.XML_FORMAT** and **google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT** but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did I workaround this?

Step1: From my WordPress Permalink Settings, I selected Custom Structure and added /%post_id%/
This means my RSS XML output results for my 'Link' element will be in this format:

```
<myurl>/<postID> (http://howtodeployit.com/111/)
```

Step2: To make it easier for me instead of writing a regex query I used a Split command like this:

```
var postlink = entry.link;
var id = postlink.split(/\//)[3];
```

**(///)[3]** would simply split the URL by the number of slashes and take only that 3rd bit which is where my postID is.

I hope this comes in handy for others in my position.